# TFLearn/Tensorflow: Proper way to save an encoder extracted from an autoencoder

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tflearn

This issue was originally posted on the tflearn github repo, but I haven't had any luck there:
https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/issues/682

I'm trying to save an encoder model that represents the middle layer from an autoencoder. Using the MNIST example, when I run the script found here:

https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/blob/master/examples/images/autoencoder.py

and then attempt to save the encoding_model using

```
encoding_model = tflearn.DNN(encoder, session=model.session)
encoding_model.save('encoder.tfl')
```

I get the following error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in  File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tflearn/models/dnn.py", line
>   260, in save self.trainer.save(model_file) File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tflearn/helpers/trainer.py",
>   line 376, in save self.saver.save(self.session, model_file,
>   global_step=global_step) File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py",
>   line 1363, in save {self.saver_def.filename_tensor_name:
>   checkpoint_file}) File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py",
>   line 767, in run run_metadata_ptr) File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py",
>   line 965, in _run feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata) File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py",
>   line 1015, in _do_run target_list, options, run_metadata) File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py",
>   line 1035, in _do_call raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
>   tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError:
>   Attempting to use uninitialized value Global_Step_1 [[Node:
>   Global_Step_1/_96 = _SendT=DT_FLOAT, client_terminated=false,
>   recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0",
>   send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0",
>   send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_31_Global_Step_1",
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]]

I think the ADAM optimizer variables are not initialized. What's the proper way to save a model like this?

Answer (score 0):

In tensorflow you don't save into a .tfl file.

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
```

and then save into a .cpkt

Check this tutorial on saving: 
https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/saved_model